# symfony association join multiple tables error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I am trying to learn symfony and have problem with joining multiple tables
however I cannt seems to connect morethan one table.

I pasted the code here: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/db8e96d0d6dd05ff7777

database schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3abc

Error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 243: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'department'
```

Any idea if iam missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

*note : First of all, your entities should start with a capital letter in your app...*

in the doc, joins look like this :

when your entity User is aliased u

```
JOIN u.address address'
```

instead of

```
JOIN Test\JoinBundle\Entity\address address
```

---

In my code :

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
            "  SELECT d"
            . " FROM Main\MainBundle\Entity\Deal d "
            . " JOIN d.contact con"
            . " JOIN con.company c"
            . " WHERE c.id = ?1"
            . " ORDER BY c.created DESC"
            );
        $query->setParameter(1, $companyId);
```

Comment: I  dont think you understood the code bro

But thanks for the capital letters

Comment: Okay i got it done but its not through relation

Here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d48ecf70b2d017e00886

But i wonder if i am missing anything in my entity relationship

Comment: there's a function I dont remember if its getSql() or getSqlQuery(), that prints you the 'raw' sql query generated, maybe it will help you.              I dont understand why you thinck i didnt get it , it's just a join, and the doc shows it as i told you...